# What cloud formation is this?

Tags: clouds

[image]

I thought it may be mammatus, but the absence of the hanging down "udders" made me doubt.

Answer (score 3):

It *is* mammatus. The individual cells *are* hanging down, but it just isn't very obvious from your perspective. Nice photo. Usually one doesn't have much time to photograph mammatus because of its inherently unstable condition.